# Same query on 2 identical DBs - different execution plans

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.6, pg-dump

I'm moving the Postgres DB to another server. After imporing the data (dumped with pg_dump) I checked the performane and found out that the same query results in different query plans on the two DBs (given that the DBMS versions, DB structure and the data itself are the same):

the query is:

```
explain analyse select * from common.composite where id = 0176200005519000087
```

query plan of the production DB:

```
Index Scan using composite_id_idx on composite  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=222) (actual time=0.070..0.071 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = '176200005519000087'::bigint)
Planning time: 0.502 ms
Execution time: 0.102 ms
```

for the new one:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on composite  (cost=581.08..54325.66 rows=53916 width=76) (actual time=0.209..0.210 rows=1 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (id = '176200005519000087'::bigint)
  Heap Blocks: exact=1
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on composite_id_idx  (cost=0.00..567.61 rows=53916 width=0) (actual time=0.187..0.187 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = '176200005519000087'::bigint)
Planning time: 0.428 ms
Execution time: 0.305 ms
```

Obviously, there is a btree index for id in both DBs. 
As far as I could get, the new one uses bitmap indeces for some reason, while btree was imported from the dump. This results in a huge delay (up to 30x) in complex queries.

Is there something wrong the the index/dependencies importing or there is a way to point which indexes the planner should use?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you run `analyze common.composite` after importing the dump? But I wouldn't consider the difference between a tenth of a millisecond and less than half a millisecond a "huge" delay

Comment: Different statistics?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I used the query just to show that they run differently, but on more complex ones I observe a massive delay.
running analyze common.composite gives the difference: 603ms vs 12.175s

Comment: @jarlh, excuse me, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: _Did_ you [update the statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) on the table(s) using `analyze` as I have asked?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that seemed to work, thanks a lot!